# What's to consider when hosting Ubuntu torrents on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, security, torrent-client, contributing

Recently, I thought about how I could contribute to the Linux / Ubuntu community, since I am a regular user for years now. One way I came up with is, that I could use my Raspberry Pi to work as a peer in the torrent distribution of several Linux distros.

However, before putting my home network at risk, I wanted to ask for guidance how to make sure that my network is safe.

Does anybody know how the Raspberry / Network should be configured?

AFAIK, probable issues might be the configuration of **port-forwarding** of the firewall, **SSH** access of the raspi, etc.

I and hopefully some users looking for a way to contribute to the ubuntu community would appreciate some guidance on this topic.

Comment: What kind of risk? Which security aspect are you concerned about? Why do you want to open ports and let SSH access be available?

Comment: This would be quite straightforward, assuming that you access the Internet through a router. The firewall in the router is your main defense against attacks from Internet. You would port-forward just one port (the torrents protocol can run on any port) towards your RPi and run a torrents client on that port. SSH is enabled by default, but the firewall will prevent SSH access from internet.

Comment: @Jos Are there any risks originating from the torrenting itself, given that I only deliver data?

Comment: You need to search for known security problems with the torrent client itself (or perhaps the protocol as a whole), and upgrade as soon as a new version is available. If no known problems exist, assume that you are safe.

Comment: @Jos Thanks for the insights. Think I will check if my SSH is actually blocked from external sources by the firewall and then I am ready to go.

Comment: You may also want to set `iptables` to accept traffic on the one port from the router, ssh from inside the lan, and nothing else.

Comment: IMHO the main concerns are bandwidth and if you ISP allows torrents or blocks them. Asking for potential security problems or how to secure a torrent server is a bit broad. See https://www.best-bittorrent-vpn.com/safe-torrent-guide.html or similar and return if you have a specific question.

Comment: One more thing: your router's firmware may occasionally turn up a vulnerability, so you need to look out for updates for that as well. If you don't mind, I'll gather all of these suggestions into an answer. However, I agree with @Panther that this is a very broad question.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely feasible. Some suggestions to enhance the security of this setup:

- The firewall in the router is your main defense against attacks from Internet. You would port-forward just one port (the torrents protocol can run on any port) towards your RPi and run a torrents client on that port.
- SSH is enabled by default, but the router's firewall will prevent SSH access from internet.
- You may also want to set `iptables` on the RPi to accept traffic on the one port from the router, `ssh` from inside the lan, and nothing else.
- You need to search for known security problems with the torrent client itself (or perhaps the protocol as a whole), and upgrade as soon as a new version is available.
- You may restrict bandwidth usage by your client, and verify that your provider allows torrents at all (trackers may be blocked).
- Your router's firmware may occasionally turn up a vulnerability, so you need to look out for updates for that as well.